Is there any way to check if point is on a heading in org mode?
I want to know if I am on a heading and not under a heading, or before all heading. Thanks.

org-at-heading-p does exactly that. Its doc string (C-h f org-at-heading-p) says:
(org-at-heading-p &optional INVISIBLE-NOT-OK)

Return t if point is on a (possibly invisible) heading line.
If INVISIBLE-NOT-OK is non-nil, an invisible heading line is not ok.


